# Free or OSS software that displays min / max / average transfer stats on Windows

Tags: open-source, statistics, data-transfer

I'm looking for a free or OSS software that displays min / max / average transfer stats on Windows at the end of a transfer.

Windows show the copy curve but does not show any stat at the end of a transfer and closes the transfer window.

I also tried [`Ultracopier`](https://sourceforge.net/projects/ultracopier) and set the `At the end of the copy` parameter to `Never`, and I get this :

[image]

Any other suggestions ?